# How to check if certain uint has 0x01000000 mask applied?

Tags: c#, bit-fields

I do some reverse engineering. There is an uint value indicating slot number where something is stored. But there is different types of storages. When something stored in different storage the value has 0x01000000 mask applied. And when it stored in one more storage the mask is 0x02000000.

My function receive this value and I need to determine storage and slot.
For example:

0x00000005 - is fifth slot in storage 0.

0x01000009 - is slot 9 in storage 1.

0x02000002 - is slot 2 in storage 2.

What is the best way to do so?

I currently do this:

```
uint test = 0x02000005;
bool bit_set_for_01 = (test & (1 << 24)) != 0;
bool bit_set_for_02 = (test & (1 << 25)) != 0;
```

But I feel this is not best thing to do.

Comment: Why do you feel that way?

Comment: Looks good to me, FWIW. -- Almost certainly the compiler will evaluate the two bit shift expressions into appropriate constants at compile-time, if performance was your concern.

Comment: @CodeCaster - well... I am not sure... maybe because it is possible for two bits to be set at once? Maybe this broken mask... Maybe I need to check for bits being exact "0 0 0 1" or "0 0 1 0"

Comment: Yes, both can be set at once. If you want them to be exclusive and show an error if both are set, you need to handle that with a different mask.

Comment: You can introduce a new type, `struct Something` with just one field to hold value and properties `uint Value`, `uint Slot`, `uint Storage` and constants `uint StorageMax`, `uint SlotMax` as well as validation in constructor, methods and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it more readable and slightly more efficient by writing something like this:

```
public static (int slot, int storage) Storage(int flags)
{
    return ((flags >> 24) & 7, flags & 0xffff);
}
```

Then:

```
static void Main()
{
    var item = Storage(0x00000005);
    Console.WriteLine($"Storage: {item.storage}, slot: {item.slot}");

    // Or just for demo:
    Console.WriteLine(Storage(0x01000009));
    Console.WriteLine(Storage(0x02000002));
}
```

Note that I'm anding with `7` above, which gives you 3 bits for slot storage (0..7 slot numbers). I'm also anding with 0xffff which gives 16 bits for the slot.

You should adjust these values to reflect the number of bits you're using for the two numbers.

Comment: This looks cool. This also solve problem when two bits represending 0x01000000 and 0x02000000 set at once, since it give me storage number greater than 2. Thanks.